# How to print other section of python on right side of screen

Tags: python, data-structures

Current output:
[image: Current output]

Code:

```
import string  
    
class TextAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text
        self._processed_text = ""
        self._letter_frequencies = {}
        
    def perform_analysis(self):
        self._preprocess_text()
        self._calculate_frequencies()
        self._generate_report()

    def _preprocess_text(self):
        # Convert text to lowercase
        processed_text = self._text.lower()

        # Remove punctuation and special characters
        processed_text = processed_text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

        # Remove numbers
        processed_text = processed_text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "0123456789"))

        # Remove extra whitespaces
        processed_text = " ".join(processed_text.split())

        # Set processed_text as an instance variable
        self._processed_text = processed_text
        #return processed_text
    
    
    def _calculate_frequencies(self):

        # Calculate letter frequencies
        for char in self._processed_text:
            if char.isalpha():  # Check if the character is a letter
                self._letter_frequencies[char] = self._letter_frequencies.get(char, 0) + 1
        #         if char in letter_frequencies:
        #             letter_frequencies[char] += 1
        #         else:
        #             letter_frequencies[char] = 1

        # return letter_frequencies

    def _generate_report(self):
        total_letters = sum(self._letter_frequencies.values())

        # Calculate letter frequencies as percentages
        frequencies_percentage = {
            letter: (self._letter_frequencies.get(letter, 0) / total_letters) * 100 for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        }

        # Find the maximum number of asterisks for scaling
        max_asterisks = max(int(percentage) for letter, percentage in frequencies_percentage.items())

        # Print formatted output with 2D representation
        # for i in range(max_asterisks, 0, -1):
        #     line = ""
        #     for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        #         percentage = frequencies_percentage.get(letter, 0)
        #         asterisks_count = 0
        #         if percentage > 0 and percentage < 4:
        #             asterisks_count = 1
        #         elif percentage >= 4 and percentage < 8:
        #             asterisks_count = 2
        #         elif percentage >= 8:
        #             asterisks_count = 3
        #         if asterisks_count >= i:
        #             line += '*'
        #         else:
        #             line += ' '
        #         line += f" | {letter.upper()}"
        #     print(line)

        # Print top 5 frequencies
        print("\nTop 5 frequencies:")
        for letter, percentage in sorted(frequencies_percentage.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:5]:
            print(f"{letter.upper()}: {percentage:.2f}%")


        for i in range(max_asterisks, 0, -1):
            #print(" " * 34, end="")
            for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                percentage = frequencies_percentage.get(letter, 0)
                asterisks_count = 0
                if percentage > 0 and percentage < 4:
                    asterisks_count = 1
                elif percentage >= 4 and percentage < 8:
                    asterisks_count = 2
                elif percentage >= 8:
                    asterisks_count = 3
                if asterisks_count >= i:
                    print('*', end="  ")
                else:
                    print(' ', end="  ")
            print()
        # Print horizontal divider
        print("_" * 75)
        # Print 2D representation with asterisks stacking on top of letters
        #print(" " * 34, end="")
        for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print(letter.upper(), end="  ")
        print()
```

```
                attempts = 0
                while attempts < 3:
                    input_file_name = input("Please enter the file you want to analyze: ")
                    if input_file_name.endswith('.txt') and os.path.exists(input_file_name):
                        input_text = Caesar.openFile(input_file_name)
                        if input_text is None:
                            print("Error: Unable to read file.")
                            attempts += 1
                        else:
                            break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid file name or file does not exist. Please include '.txt' extension.")
                        attempts += 1
                else:
                    print("Failed to read the file after 3 attempts. Returning to the main menu.")
                    continue  # Continue to the next iteration of the main menu loop

                
                analyzer = TextAnalyzer(input_text)
                print(analyzer) 
                analyzer.perform_analysis()
```

This is my intended output:
[image: intended output]

I managed to print the left side of the screen, but when ever I try to print the right side I'm led with this error:

[image: error]

The file is a saved notepad `txt` with content:

```
"Twinkle, twinkle little star,
how I wonder what you are.

Up above the sky so high,
like a diamond in the sky."
```

I have no issues with the asterics, but really scratched my brain hard on how to obtain both right size of the screen output as I am using for loop to generate it .

Comment: don't add links to imgs when not needed. Copy paste as plain text or use inline imgs

Comment: @cards i cant copy and paste image yet as im still new to stackoverflow, please help with the question. Thank you.

Comment: @cards in this case, I think the images are appropriate as they demonstrate intended layout rather than code.

Comment: Please don't alter questions with intent to remove the meaning. In some cases this could be viewed as a vandalism. One thing to keep in mind that when someone answers they are not answering just for you, but for everyone else in the future who has a question like this.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372007/should-we-say-vandalizing-to-refer-to-defaced-content

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to recognize that we need to build the output on a row by row basis and build the contents of each row manually.

That means, matching the main content of each cell of the row with the number of characters we count but also appending to that the percentages of the current letter in the vertical context of each row. Complicating that, some rows must be handled as a special case in order to finally append the "Top" information.

Take it slowly and deliberately and you should be able to puzzle it out.

```py
import collections
import string

original_text = """
Twinkle twinkle litter star, how I wonder what you are.
Up above the sky so high, like a diamond in the sky.
"""

## ----------------------
## Complete alphabet
## ----------------------
all_letters = string.ascii_uppercase
all_letters_count = len(all_letters)
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## Clean up the text
## convert to upper case and remove non-alpha characters
## ----------------------
cleaned_letters = list(filter(str.isalpha, original_text.upper()))
cleaned_letters_count = len(cleaned_letters)
## ----------------------

## ----------------------
## count each character
## ----------------------
individual_letter_counts = collections.Counter(cleaned_letters)
top_5_letter_counts = individual_letter_counts.most_common(5)
## ----------------------

for row_index in range(all_letters_count):
    row = []

    ## ----------------
    ## For the given row and column what plyph should we print
    ## ----------------
    for letter in all_letters:
        count = individual_letter_counts.get(letter, 0)
        glyph = " " if all_letters_count - row_index > count else "*"
        row.append(glyph)
    ## ----------------

    ## ----------------
    ## right side percentages
    ## ----------------
    side_letter = all_letters[row_index]
    side_letter_pct = 100 * individual_letter_counts.get(side_letter, 0) / cleaned_letters_count
    row.append(f"| {side_letter}- {side_letter_pct:>5.2f}%")
    ## ----------------

    ## ----------------
    ## right side top
    ## ----------------
    if row_index == 0:
        row.append("  TOP 5 FREQ")
    if row_index == 1:
        row.append("  ------------")
    if row_index in [2,3,4,5,6]:
        top_letter, top_count = top_5_letter_counts[row_index - 2]
        top_letter_pct = 100 * top_count / cleaned_letters_count
        row.append(f"  | {top_letter}- {top_letter_pct:>5.2f}%")
    ## ----------------

    print(" ".join(row))

print(f"{'_' * all_letters_count * 2}|")
print(" ".join(all_letters))
```

That should give you:

```
                                                    | A-  7.23%   TOP 5 FREQ
                                                    | B-  1.20%   ------------
                                                    | C-  0.00%   | E- 10.84%
                                                    | D-  3.61%   | T-  9.64%
                                                    | E- 10.84%   | I-  9.64%
                                                    | F-  0.00%   | A-  7.23%
                                                    | G-  1.20%   | H-  7.23%
                                                    | H-  7.23%
                                                    | I-  9.64%
                                                    | J-  0.00%
                                                    | K-  6.02%
                                                    | L-  4.82%
                                                    | M-  1.20%
                                                    | N-  6.02%
                                                    | O-  7.23%
                                                    | P-  1.20%
                                                    | Q-  0.00%
        *                                           | R-  4.82%
        *       *                     *             | S-  4.82%
        *       *                     *             | T-  9.64%
*       *     * *           *         *             | U-  2.41%
*       *     * *   *     * *         *     *       | V-  1.20%
*       *     * *   * *   * *     * * *     *       | W-  6.02%
*     * *     * *   * *   * *     * * *     *   *   | X-  0.00%
*     * *     * *   * *   * *     * * * *   *   *   | Y-  3.61%
* *   * *   * * *   * * * * * *   * * * * * *   *   | Z-  0.00%
____________________________________________________|
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Comment: hello, Thanks for your solution. Is it possible to delete your answer for both questions am I am being stalked, I would really appreciate if you did that. Thank you.